# Ravendb Savechanges(); taking too long time to run?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

Ran into a weird problem with RavenDB

```
public ActionResult Save(RandomModel model)
{
//Do some stuff, validate model etc..

RavenSession.Store(model);
RavenSession.SaveChanges();


var newListOfModels = RavenSession.Query<RandomModel>().ToList();
return View("randomview",newListOfModels);
}
```

The newListOfModels does not contain the model i just added with the store method.

However, if i add a Thread.Sleep(100) after savechanges the stored model is included in the new list.

Am i storing and Saving stuff to RavenDB the wrong way?

How should i be doing this?

Of course there is a work around by just adding the incoming model to the newListOfModels and running SaveChanges after for example in a basecontrollers onactionexecuted method.

My primary concern is why i need to delay the thread before i can query the documentsession and find my newly added model there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RavenDB indexes are stale by their nature. [From the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes):

> RavenDB performs data indexing in a background thread, which is
>   executed whenever new data comes in or existing data is updated.
>   Running this as a background thread allows the server to respond
>   quickly even when large amounts of data have changed, however in that
>   case you may query stale indexes.

So you need to tell RavenDB when querying to wait for the index to be refressed.

You can do with the various `WaitFor...` customization, you will most probably want the `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite` option:

```
var newListOfModels = RavenSession
    .Query<RandomModel>()
    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Always nice to learn new stuff about this awesome db